# Spring Boot + Jetty 9 + Jersey 2.11 Asynchronous not supported

Tags: gradle, jersey, jetty, spring-boot

I am building a project using Spring Boot, Jetty 9 and Jersey 2.11 and I am not getting able to use the asynchronous features.

If I decompress the generated jar by the Gradle Spring Boot plugin I can see the `javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar` inside the lib directory but I get the asynchronous processing not supported error

I have created a repo at https://bitbucket.org/quaiks/spring-boot-jetty-jersey with a sample project. Just 3 classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have something on the classpath that provides an implementation of `AsyncContextDelegateProvider`. Update your `build.gradle` to add a runtime dependency on `org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.11`.